# How to get job name from a Sink (or RichFunction in general) w/o using REST API?

Tags: java, apache-flink

As captioned. While `getJobId` is available from `RuntimeContext`, job name isn't available.

https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.13/api/java/org/apache/flink/api/common/functions/RuntimeContext.html

Trying to get it from Configuration doesn't seem to work as well:

```java
  @Override
  public void open(Configuration parameters) throws Exception {
    String jobName = parameters.getString(PipelineOptions.NAME); // this is null
  }
```

This is how we run a standalone sample pipeline:

```java
  public static void main(String... args) {
    try {
      ParameterTool parameterTool = ParameterTool.fromArgs(args);

      final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
      // some pipeline setup
      env.execute("This-is-job-name");
    } catch (Exception e) {
      // logging
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are passing in the job name as a parameter to the job, you want to set it up like this:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    ParameterTool parameterTool = ParameterTool.fromArgs(args);
    final StreamExecutionEnvironment env =
      StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

    env.getConfig().setGlobalJobParameters(parameters);
```

and then this should work

```
@Override
public void open(Configuration parameters) throws Exception {
    ParameterTool params = (ParameterTool)
      getRuntimeContext().getExecutionConfig().getGlobalJobParameters();
    
    String jobName = params.get(nameOfParameterWithJobName);
}
```

The Configuration passed to `open` is always empty -- that's an obsolete mechanism that is no longer used. The method signature hasn't been changed in order to avoid breaking a public API.

Another good way to pass info like this to a RichFunction is to pass it to the constructor.